# Transposing matrix twice using classes without numpy

Tags: python, matrix

I need to implement a method transpose() that returns a new matrix that has been transposed. It also has to print out a string of that matrix. It works when using matrix.transpose() but it doesn't work when using matrix.transpose().transpose() because transpose() returns a string.
I can't use numpy or add more input to the methods. How would I go about this?

```
from copy import deepcopy


class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.rows = rows[:]
```

```
    def transpose(self):
            copy = deepcopy(self.rows)
            transposed = [[copy[j][i] for j in range(len(copy))] for i in range(len(copy[0]))]

        matrix = ''
        for element in transposed:
            for i in element:
                matrix += '%2d' % ((i))
                matrix += ' '
            matrix = matrix[:-1]
            matrix += '\n'


       return matrix
```

```
a = Matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `Matrix` object in `transpose` and return that after printing its content.
For convenience I moved your printing code to a method for converting the matrix to a string (Note that a method called `__repr__` will be implicit called by print).
Code:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

class Matrix:
     def __init__(self, rows):
         self.rows = rows[:]

     def transpose(self):
         copy = deepcopy(self.rows)
         transposed = [[copy[j][i] for j in range(len(copy))] for i in range(len(copy[0]))]
         transposed_matrix = Matrix(transposed)
         print(transposed_matrix)
         return transposed_matrix

     def __repr__(self):
         matrix = ''
         for element in self.rows:
             for i in element:
                 matrix += '%2d' % ((i))
                 matrix += ' '
             matrix = matrix[:-1]
             matrix += '\n'
         return matrix
```

Additional improvements:

- in `transpose` you can change the matrix transposition to `transposed = list(map(list, zip(*self.rows)))`
- use format string instead of `'%2d' % ((i))` -> `f'{i:2}'`
- `join` is very helpful for formatting the matrix:
  `return '\n'.join(' '.join(f'{i:2}' for i in row) for row in self.rows)`

Now the full code looks like this

```py
class Matrix:
     def __init__(self, rows):
         self.rows = rows[:]

     def transpose(self):
         transposed = list(map(list, zip(*self.rows)))
         transposed_matrix = Matrix(transposed)
         print(transposed_matrix)
         return transposed_matrix

     def __repr__(self):
         return '\n'.join(' '.join(f'{i:2}' for i in row) for row in self.rows)
```